# How can we use MSHTML with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, mshtml

I saw a lot of examples in MSDN on how to use MSHTML in VS. Have anyone known if and how we can use MSHTML and VBA to open web pages?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the VBA editor, you go under Tools -> References and add a reference to the Microsoft HTML Object Library [MSHTML.TLB].  Here is [a link](http://p2p.wrox.com/excel-vba/20672-problem-using-mshtml.html) with an example in VBA.